# How to give spaces in orientDB fields alias name

Tags: orientdb

i want to give space between words in alias name like first_name has to be 
'First Name'.
i tried this query (SELECT first_name AS 'First Name' FROM employee) but it
showing query parsing error.

Comment: You may try wit ` (backtick) instead of '

Comment: yes i tried but it's thrown illegal argument exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try SELECT first_name AS (backtick)First\nName(backtick) FROM employee